# Subscription key error

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to send a Bing News Search API request with the following Python 3 code:

```
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '#####################',
}
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'q': 'test search',
    'count': 20,
})
try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/bing/v5.0/news/?%s" % params, "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
super(GetPages, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Every time, I get the error

```
b'{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }'
```

Not sure what the error is (though I'm new to all this, so I know I could be making a very simple mistake). It's persisted after regenerating the keys and waiting 10 minutes. I'm able to use Bing text analytics using the other key on the same Cognitive Services account.

Comment: <removed previous comment>  
This is working fine with a new account for me.  Have you tried the test console?

https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56f02400dbe2d91900c68553/console


Text analytics uses a different set of keys.  Are you sure you have the right one?

Comment: I have tried the test console—it doesn't work there either. What do you mean that text analytics uses a different set of keys, though? My cognitive services account came with two keys total. Bing news search and text analytics both seem to be listed under the Cognitive Services APIs. I'm using one key for a text analytics API call, and I'm trying to use the other for a News search one. Is that incorrect?

Comment: When you go to request a trial for a service, you can check "Bing Search - Free" and "Text Analytics - Preview" in the list.  These are different products. When you do so, you will get 2 keys for each products, for a total of 4 keys between both of them.  The keys for Bing Search will not work for Analytics, and vice-versa.

Comment: Ah I see, it's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to request a trial for a service, you can check "Bing Search - Free" and "Text Analytics - Preview" in the list. These are different products. When you do so, you will get 2 keys for each products, for a total of 4 keys between both of them. The keys for Bing Search will not work for Analytics, and vice-versa.